# BitmapIconSource in a ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, resourcedictionary

I would like to change the BitmapIcon of a NavigationViewItem depending on the current Windows theme.

I've added a `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` to the MainPage like that:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap"
                                UriSource="/Assets/Images/ProduccioBlau.png" />
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap"
                                UriSource="/Assets/Images/Produccio.png" />
            </ResourceDictionary>


            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap"
                                UriSource="/Assets/Images/Produccio.png" />
            </ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then in the NavigationViewItem:

```cs
<NavigationViewItem Content="Ordres fabricació"
                    Tag="OrdresFabricacio">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="{ThemeResource ProductionBitmap}"
                    ShowAsMonochrome="False" />
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

But I get a squiggling line on `UriSource="{ThemeResource ProductionBitmap}"` saying:

> The resource ProductionBitmap has an incompatible type.

**What is the proper way to use a themed resource in this case?**

The application compiles without errors, but I get an exception at run time when the themed resource is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't set the value of the `UriSource` property of the **BitmapIcon** in such a way. You could directly store the string value of the path of the image in the **ResourceDictionary**. Then using `ThemeResource` to get the string value.

Like this:

```
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <x:String x:Key="ProductionBitmap" >/Assets/london.png</x:String>
                <!--<BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap" UriSource="/Assets/london.png" />-->
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <x:String x:Key="ProductionBitmap" >/Assets/paris.png</x:String>
                <!--<BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap"  UriSource="/Assets/paris.png" />-->
            </ResourceDictionary>


            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <x:String x:Key="ProductionBitmap" >/Assets/paris.png</x:String>
                <!--<BitmapIconSource x:Key="ProductionBitmap" UriSource="/Assets/paris.png" />-->
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Use it like this:

```
  <BitmapIcon UriSource="{ThemeResource ProductionBitmap}"  ShowAsMonochrome="False" />
```